# Programa que advinhe um número secreto usando bisection search

Tags: python, python-3.x

Crie um programa que advinhe um número secreto usando bisection search !

O usuário pensa em um inteiro entre 0 (inclusive) e 100 (não inclusive). O computador, usando bisection search, dá um palpite e o usuário responde com h (alto), l (baixo) ou c (certo)

O computador dará palpites até acertar.

Meu código:

```
print("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!")
print("#Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.\
      Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.\
      Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.") 

#Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.
#Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. 

inicio =0
fim =100
meio = round((inicio +fim)/2)
guess = input("Is your secret number {}?:".format(meio))

while guess != "c":

    if guess == "h":
        fim =meio
        meio = round((inicio + fim)/2)
        guess = input("Is your secret number {}?:".format(meio))
    elif guess == "l":
        inio =meio
        meio = round((inio  +fim)/2)
        guess = input("Is your secret number {}?:".format(meio))
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")
        guess = input("Is your secret number {}?:".format(meio))
print("Game over. Your secret number was:{}".format(meio))
```

O que está errado com o código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do [Pedro von Hertwig](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/5878), que apontou o erro do seu código.

Consegue perceber que você utilizou no seu código quatro vezes a função `input` exatamente com a mesma mensagem? Isso é um indicativo que seu código pode não estar muito bem estruturado. Ao perceber, é sempre bom revisar sua lógica e identificar os pontos que se repetem. Por exemplo, é possível reescrever o seu código da seguinte maneira:

```
print('''Please think of a number between 0 and 100!

Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.
Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.
Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.
''')

start = 0
stop = 100

while True:
    guess = (start + stop) // 2
    response = input(f'Is your secret number {guess}? ')
    if response == 'c':
        break
    elif response == 'h':
        stop = guess
    else:
        start = guess

print(f'Game over. Your secret number was: {guess}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PlaintiveHandsomeThing)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Um erro de digitação te fez criar uma nova variável.

```
elif guess == "l":
    inio =meio
    meio = round((inio  +fim)/2)
    guess = input("Is your secret number {}?:".format(meio))
```

deveria ser:

```
elif guess == "l":
    inicio = meio
    meio = round((inicio  +fim)/2)
    guess = input("Is your secret number {}?:".format(meio))
```

Comment: Na verdade, fui passar este programa em um testador automático do edx e recebi o erro: https://ibb.co/nkGpBn

Comment: consegue entender o que está acontencendo?